# Trying to get an SVN running on a VM using a bridged connection and accessed from WAN using a DDNS

Tags: networking, svn, vmware-workstation, visualsvn-server, ddns

I am trying to get an SVN to run from a Windows 8 VM and accessed from a distant computer via WAN.
I am using a VMWare Workstation 9 for the VM and the host is Windos 8 and the guest is Windows 8 also, I am using VisualSVN for the server and NO-IP to giv my pc a DNS even though it doesn't have a static IP.

the VM gets a IPv4 address of it's own and when i try to go to the DNS via a browser i get the router config page and when i try to go to the dns from a browser on a pc over WAN i get:
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Itay.